# I need help to identify the instruments of a composition (in a movie)

Tags: instruments, orchestra, string-instruments

Probably this is very easy to answer for people who know the composition of an orchestra and which sound comes from which instrument. My question is, what is the instrument (or the composition of instruments) between 1:52 and 1:55? 
Is this the double bass or a combination of bass and some violins or violas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are surely violoncelli and double basses playing very sharply. May be the instruments are samples: the kind of sound reminds me of the Iconica instruments of Steinberg which I recognize in TV movie productions (especially *thrillers*).

You can add brass instruments (tubas, trombones, baritones) or also a bassoon ad lib. to get this sound.

compare your passage with 3:36  in the following link:

Comment: This plugin looks amazing, but 800USD is pretty expensive (the whole Ableton Suite I use cost me the half of this price).